# Showing the Soft Keyboard manually with InputMethodManager does not adjust the window

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

So I have an Activity that is using `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, and I have a `OnPreDrawListener` for an `EditText` that calls:

```
editText.requestFocus();
inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
```

Which works as expected and pushes the `Activity` up to make room for the `EditText`. However, if I dismiss the keyboard with the back button (which pans the window back to the original location), then touch the `EditText` again to show the keyboard, the keyboard shows, but the window does not adjust.

I've even tried adding an `OnClickListener` to the `EditText` and calling the same two calls again:

```
editText.requestFocus();
inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
```

But the window does not pan until I dismiss the window and show it again. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try calling hideSoftInputFromWindow on onBackPressed, just a trick to get what you want

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not exactly a *solution* to the problem, but it's the workaround I ended up going with. I created a subclass of `LinearLayout` to intercept the back button press before the IME receives it:

```
public class IMEInterceptLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    //For some reason, the event seems to occur twice for every back press
    //so track state to avoid firing multiple times
    private boolean notifiedListener = false;
    private OnBackPressedPreIMEListener listener;

    public IMEInterceptLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public IMEInterceptLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public IMEInterceptLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setOnBackPressedPreIMEListener(OnBackPressedPreIMEListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    private void fireOnBackPressedPreIME() {
        if(listener != null && !notifiedListener) {
            listener.onBackPressedPreIME();
            notifiedListener = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            fireOnBackPressedPreIME();
            return true;
        } else return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
    }

    public interface OnBackPressedPreIMEListener {
        public void onBackPressedPreIME();
    }
}
```

Then from there I just registered my window as a listener for the layout, and dismiss the window and the keyboard when I receive the event, disallowing the keyboard to be dismissed while the window is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this three steps will solve your problem.

1)in manifest file change windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
to **windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**

2) The layout you are using for EditText , tha change the parent layout to ScroolView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittextview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="textFilter"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</ScrollView>
```

3) To explicitly showing keyboard to avoid "dismiss the keyboard with the back button and window is not Adjust" 
in Edittext onclick write

```
edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (m != null) {
                    m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    edittext.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the third option a try tomorrow; changing to a `ScrollView` and `adjustResize` is not the desired behavior though; it needs to pan, not resize the window.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, the same problem still occurs.